# Why is specifying a defined constant inside a class constant throwing an error?

Tags: php

Here is part of my code

```
define('DIR_APP', 'app/');

 class Questions
    {


        const QUESTIONS_FILE = DIR_APP . 'questions.xml';
    }
```

Seems when I take the `define()`'d constant out of my class constant declaration, it works fine. But when I add it it throws this error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '.', expecting ',' or ';' in /home/public_html/app/classes/Questions.class.php on line 7
```

So how can I get my `define()`'d constant in there? I assume it is not correctly looking up the `DIR_APP` thinking it might of been defined within the class. How do I get it to resolve it globally?

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It can't be done.

Quote from http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.constants.php :

> "The value must be a constant
>   expression, not (for example) a
>   variable, a class member, result of a
>   mathematical operation or a function
>   call"

I think you could

> define('QUESTIONS_FILE', DIR_APP .
>   'questions.xml');

but that is global.

Comment: That sucks... so I'm left with global defines or normal variables? Has anyone else ran into this problem before?

Comment: I'm new to php but I guess having a const as a class member is the same in memory use as having it globally. You could see if that is the case by measuring memory increase when you define all consts outside class def and while defining them in the class, before instantiating it.

Answer (score 0):

Never tried that before. Zend Studio is giving me an issue at the moment to look at it myself. How about trying this though...

```
const QUESTIONS_FILE = constant("DIR_APP") . 'questions.xml';
```

Comment: It choked on the parenthesis :(

Comment: Gah! What version of PHP are you running?